# sending email using mailgun

Tags: django, mailgun, django-mailgun

```
def send_complex_message():
    return requests.post(
         "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
         auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
         files=[("attachment", ("test.jpg", open("files/test.jpg","rb").read())),
                ("attachment", ("test.txt", open("files/test.txt","rb").read()))],
         data={"from": "Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
             "to": "foo@example.com",
             "cc": "baz@example.com",
             "bcc": "bar@example.com",
             "subject": "Hello",
             "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
             "html": "<html>HTML version of the body</html>"})
```

this is the code from mailgun documentation.
i need to access the value of "text" within "html".
is there a way that i could do  that.

Comment: fyi, I removed the unrelated tag `PHP` from your post

Comment: what do you mean 'I need to access the value of text'? It's just a string in this code example. You can assign it any string variable you want.

Comment: actually i need to know that how can i call a variable inside the html part in the code given above